# How to check in which server mode (e.g. SuperClassic or Superserver) a Firebird database is running?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

The latest Firebird 2.5.x database can run in either Classic, SuperClassic, or SuperServer mode. How can I check in which of these modes an installed database is running?

Comment: From application or on a server?

Comment: On a server. But an application like Flamerobin won't tell me either. It allows me to retrieve the database version, but not the server mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no API that exposes this. But because you're on a server, you can check what process is running.

I.e. on Windows and Firebird 2.5:

- One `fb_inet_server.exe` = very likely SuperClassic
- Multiple `fb_inet_server.exe` = very likely Classic
- `fbserver.exe` = very likely SuperServer

Comment: What if I am in client? I can't retrieve the executable file name from client.

Comment: The client should not have a knowledge on server edition. If you need to, you're doing probably something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Firebird 4+ has RDB$CONFIG table.
To read ServerMode see record with rdb$config_name='ServerMode':

```
select rdb$config_value from RDB$CONFIG where rdb$config_name='ServerMode'
```